# Estimating multiple populations

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, estimation

I have a set of sequential data of unknown size randomly spread across $n$ locations.

I am trying to estimate the population size of all $n$ locations and provide a confidence interval as well. This problem is similar to the german tank problem, but has the added nuiance of having the data spread over multiple locations.

For example, my data could look like this. I have locations $A$, $B$, and $C$. I have a sample for each location of varying sizes.

$A= \{10,14,15,31,38,47,48\}$

$B= \{8,20,21,23,52,57 \}$

$C= \{ 2,7,41,37,17 \}$

Comment: So you are looking for 3 size estimates and 3 confidence intervals, one for each location? Do you know anything about the sampling? That is, is a location with a larger set of items sampled more often than one with only a few items? Is the sampling with or without replacement?